# How can one generate a dict in Jinja/Ansible as a var?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I need to dynamically generate a dict and assign it to an Ansible var so that the same data is available to every host and does not need to be regenerated on each one. This will be looped over by a task and template. It is possible to build lists by nesting Jinja in a var definition like so:

```
var_list: >
  [
    {% set data = [] %}
    {% for host in groups['all'] %}
    {{ data.append(host) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ data }}
  ]
```

However, I am not able to do so with dicts:

```
var_dict: >
  {
    {% set data = dict() %}
    {% for host in groups['all'] %}
    {{ data | combine({host: []}) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ data }}
  }
```

This results in a giant, garbled string: `{u'host.subdom.dom.tld': []} {}`...

What I am expecting is a var set to a true dict object that can have its components referenced individually (like `{{ var_dict.host1[0] }}`), with a structure similar to the following JSON:

```
{
  "host1": [],
  "host2": []
}
```

Is there a way to cause this to expand into a proper dict when assigned to the variable? Or is there perhaps another way to generate a dict from a loop without that [awful `set_fact` hackery](https://serverfault.com/questions/685673/appending-to-lists-or-adding-keys-to-dictionaries-in-ansible)?

Comment: Can you post as example of what you want the resulting dict to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either of your templates is broken (the first one produces nested lists, the second one prints data in loop with this expression `{{ data | combine({host: []}) }}`, the value of `data` remains empty until the end).

---

Jinja2 is a templating engine, you don't really need to create data structures to print them later. You can form your output directly.

For the list:

```
var_list: >
  [ {% for host in groups['all'] %}'{{ host }}',{% endfor %} ]
```

For the dictionary:

```
var_dict: >
  { {% for host in groups['all'] %}'{{ host }}': [],{% endfor %} }
```

---

<sup>As you expect the values to be interpreted by Ansible, you don't need to pay attention to the trailing coma, otherwise there is [loop.last](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#for).</sup>

Comment: The reason I want to do it this way is to populate the dict with more data inside the lists, which I am having an additional addressing problem with that I was planning to save for another post so it didn't look like two questions at once. Should I re-write the post to include the full use case and both issues?

Comment: I did not mean to offend or dismiss the work that you put in. I will accept this answer and post a new question, as you have answered the original question as written. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Well, you can post a new question, but the mechanism stays the same - you create a JSON string with `[`, `]`, quotes, and comas printed literally, then you use statements for flow control (and as you want lists, it will most likely be a `for` loop as in the first example) and expressions for referring to the data.